# Copy Directories Recursively From Ftp Server Using Perl

Tags: perl, ftp

I need to write a perl script which has to log in to an FTP server and download all the sub-directories and contents on sub-directories to local machine. The version of Perl on the FTP server is 5.8.8, i can't upgrade it. One method is to create directories on local machine and then copy each file. I was wondering if there is any command to copy a directory and its content. Is it possible to "tar" the directory to save space?

Thanks,
Amit.

Comment: Have you tried `wget`? BTW, the version of Perl on the FTP server is irrelevant.

Comment: @SinanÜnür ya makes sense...the perl version thr is not imp

Answer (score 2):

There is [Net::FTP::Recursive](http://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aFTP%3a%3aRecursive). I haven't tried it but it seems to fit your requirements.